# How can i make the entire row of a table clickable in react js using <Link> or any other way?

Tags: reactjs

here is the code

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <Link to={{pathname: '/user',
                 state: {
                   number: content.number,
                   name: content.name,
                   age: content.age
                 }
               }}
      />
     {content.accountOwner}
    </td>
    <td>
      {content.address}
   </td>
   <td>{content.profession}</td
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

This row becomes clickable in chrome but in IE as the  is put in the first column, only the first column becomes clickable and not the entire row.
Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.push()` method to programatically navigate to that page.
If you are using the latest `react-router-dom` you can use the `useHistory` hook to be able to use the push method.
Another advantage from `push()` will not break your UI, since the `<Link />` component could cause problems in your UI since it's another element nested.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

export const ExampleComponent = ({ content }) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  function handleRowClick() {
    const { number, name, age } = content;
    history.push('/user', { number, name, age });
  }

  return (
    <tbody>
      <tr onClick={handleRowClick}>
        <td>
          {content.accountOwner}
        </td>
        <td>
          {content.address}
        </td>
        <td>{content.profession}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  )
};
```

Comment: Well good question, it's possible, what's left here it's the styles so you will need to add some hover, active styles to be "clickable".

Comment: Actually, how do you maintain contextual menu actions with `onClick`? For example, being able to ctrl+click to open in new tab, and also right-click > copy table row address as link, etc.